# How to open a LaTeX document where the mouse cursor points in DVI with Kile? (Inverse Search)

Tags: linux, kile, dvi, forward-inverse-search

I think I have heard about that in somewhere but don't know where.

I'm using Kile and Okular on Ubuntu, so I appreciate a solution for it. (But I think it's not depends of Kile.) But other ideas are welcome.

I tried install kvdi but there isn't this package anymore. What package I could install to enable this inverse search together with Kile?

Comment: Are you referring to [inverse search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_search)?

Comment: Yes! I have installed TeX Live 2011 and configured it... how can I use this scrltx in Okular and Kile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that *it does not really depend of Kile* just double click on DVI. If you will be lucky you will move focus on desired place in your source file. If not... then you will know for sure that it depends on Kile. If so see help file and look for Inverse DVI Search.

PS. This also works in [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) wich is now my favorite viewer for PDF.

Comment: I tried configure okular to use Kile in Editor option...but it doesn't worked...what can I do?

Comment: Thx. I have found this tuto...it works [Tuto](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/extragear-office/kile/quick_inverse.html),
[Auxiliar](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/extragear-office/kile/quick_forward.html)